# Adding Remix OS on grub customizer

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

I am having trouble adding Remix OS to my grub.  I made a partition in my hard drive and put the ISO extracted files in that partition.  I open grub customizer and make a custom entry.  my problem is I don't know to set up the custom boot sequence.  can anyone help me? I have a partition at sda7 on my main hard drive titled Remix OS, inside that drive are all the files from the Remix OS ISO download except the boot folder.  How do I write a custom boot sequence for this?

Comment: can u share your partition screenshoot ?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/remix/remix-os/how-to-install-remix-os-alongside-t3352890